# Get file path from tcp packet

Tags: file, sockets, networking, tcp, path

I have an app wich download a file from a server, receiving it in tcp packets and I want to found the path of file on the server. With wireshark I read in the first packet some information like date, domain, file name and as path I read `path=/` but it isn't in domain.com/filename (404). Is there any way to get the real path where the file is on the server?

edit:

All I found comprehensible in the first packet:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 30 Aug 2014 14:35:55 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.24
Set-Cookie: frontend=m90hqgtsu70hk9pprd39sllqk4; expires=Sat, 30-Aug-2014 25:35:55 GMT; path=/; domain=www.exaple.com; HttpOnly
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="xxx.y"
Content-Length: 46458848
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
```

The request:

```
GET /index.php/rest/server?method=download&sessionId=xxx&userId=a@a.com&deviceToken=xxx&sku=filename&version=2
HTTP/1.1
Connection: Keep-Alive
Accept Encoding: gzip
Accept-Language: it-IT,en,*
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0
Host: www.domain.com
```

Comment: What protocol are you using to download the file? What does the packet actually look like? You say the packet has `domain`, `path` and `filename` components, have you tried simply combining them together?

Comment: I didn't write the application, so I don't know how exactly it works. Now I'll add to the question all I read in the packet which is comprensible. As I said I tried to combine domain, path and filename but it isn't there (404).

Answer (score 1):

The file is being downloaded using HTTP (read [RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616)).  The packet you are looking at is a response. The domain and path information you are looking for is not in the response, it is in the request instead:

```
GET /index.php/rest/server?method=download&sessionId=xxx&userId=a@a.com&deviceToken=xxx&sku=filename&version=2 HTTP/1.1
Connection: Keep-Alive
Accept Encoding: gzip
Accept-Language: it-IT,en,*
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0
Host: www.domain.com
```

So the URL to request the file would be `http://www.domain.com/index.php/rest/server?method=download&sessionId=xxx&userId=a@a.com&deviceToken=xxx&sku=filename&version=2`.

The `filename` you see in the response is the actual filename for the file.  But not all responses will include such a filename, so be prepared for that. If there is no `Content-Disposition` header (or it does not have a `filename` attribute), look for a `name` attribute in the `Content-Type` header.  If none, you will have to parse the request URL (see [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986)) looking for a filename in its [`Path`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.3) component (in the above URL, that is `/index.php/rest/server`).

The `domain` and `path` pieces you see in the response are not related to the file at all.  They belong to a cookie (see [RFC 6265](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265)) that is used to persist server-side data between HTTP requests.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately in the request I don't see the file path but only the file name, it's a request to a php page

Comment: I assure you, the request does provide enough information to reconstruct the URL needed to request the file.  Not all URLs have full paths/filenames in them, but that is OK.  The URL is still valid, the server knows how to interpret it, and if it serves up a file, the response will describe it (just not its location, usually - although HTTP does define a `Location:` header that is sometimes used). If you want more help, please show the HTTP request.

Comment: In the php request there are some parameters, I think the server checks them and then returns the file if the they are correct. For this I wanted to go directly to the file, but now I think it's not possible

Comment: In some cases, it is sometimes possible to figure out the direct URL and bypass a script, but usually not. A script has to process the parameters first to decide what to return back, and in the case of files, they are usually in an inaccessible location for obvious reasons.

Comment: If I change the parameters, it send me an error page. Now I'll add the request in the question

Comment: I tried to parse the url, but I don't see file names in path component (I'm not sure if the parse I have done it's right):  
`Array  (  
    [scheme] => http  
    [host] => www.domain.com  
    [path] => /index.php/rest/server/path  
)`

Comment: Parsing a filename from a URL is a last-ditch effort when everything else fails, so it is not going to work every time. Once you have extracted the Path component, parse its content for something that resembles a filename ('index.php' for instance). What do you think a web browser does when it asks you to save a file it wasn't told the filename for? Right, it has to make some educated guesses, or just make up a filename. You will have to do the same thing. In your example, `Content-Disposition` told you the filename.

Answer (score 0):

If the server does not voluntarily provide the path you are looking for there is no way to find out. The file it sends might not even *be* on disk. It might be generated data or data cached in application memory.

If the response does not contain the path (and that is unlikely because no server I know of would send it) you can't do anything to find it.